# Open link always in same tab. (chrome)

Tags: javascript, html, hyperlink

Using the `HTML target` attribute this can be easy done on Firefox which you can see here: https://jsfiddle.net/4v2yzmLx/7/. What about Chrome, I cannot figure it out.

Answer (score 0):

In HTML, the target attribute can handle the following values (This works on any browser):

`_blank`: Open the link in a new tab.

`_top`: Open the link in the same tab.

For more you can visit this site:
https://www.w3schools.com/tags/att_a_target.asp

So in your case you must use the `_self` value to open it in the same tab:

```
 <a href="http://google.com/" target="_self">Click me</a>
```

Comment: Still keeps opening new tabs on each click in my Chrome browser. I have Chrome 51 on Ubuntu OS.

Comment: Can you try with _self ?

Comment: Self doesn't open a tab but opens the link in the same window.

Comment: Is that what you want?